# Proper usage of tensorflows STFT function

Tags: audio, tensorflow

I am trying to construct a plot spectrum of an audio sample similar to the one that is created using Audacity. From Audacity's wiki page, the plot spectrum (attached example) performs:

> Plot Spectrum take the audio in blocks of 'Size' samples, does the
>   FFT, and averages all the blocks together.

[image]

I was thinking I would use the STFT functionality recently provided by Tensorflow.

I am using audio blocks of size 512, and my code is as follows:

```
audio_binary = tf.read_file(audio_file)
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(
    audio_binary,
    file_format="wav",
    samples_per_second=4000,
    channel_count=1
)

stft = tf.contrib.signal.stft(
    waveform,
    512,     # frame_length
    512,     # frame_step
    fft_length=512,
    window_fn=functools.partial(tf.contrib.signal.hann_window, periodic=True), # matches audacity
    pad_end=True,
    name="STFT"
)
```

But the results of stft are is just an empty array when I expect the FFT results for each frame (of 512 samples)

What is wrong with the way that I am making this call?

I have verified that waveform audio data is being correctly read with just the regular `tf.fft` function.

Comment: I figured it out... `tf.contrib.signal.stft` takes multiple signals each with their own signal data. So it will be of the form (signals, signal_data). 

`tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio` returns data for a single signal of the form (signal_data, 1).

So I needed to transpose `waveform`

Answer (score 0):

```
audio_file = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

audio_binary = tf.read_file(audio_file)
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(
    audio_binary,
    file_format="wav",
    samples_per_second=sample_rate,    # Get Info on .wav files (sample rate)
    channel_count=1             # Get Info on .wav files (audio channels)
)

stft = tf.contrib.signal.stft(
    tf.transpose(waveform),
    frame_length,     # frame_lenght, hmmm
    frame_step,     # frame_step, more hmms
    fft_length=fft_length,
    window_fn=functools.partial(tf.contrib.signal.hann_window, 
            periodic=False), # matches audacity
    pad_end=False,
    name="STFT"
)
```

Comment: Note: this function was deprecated in 2018-09-04